# Replacement for Go App Engine "google.golang.org/appengine/log" package, with log levels?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-app-engine-go, google-app-engine-golang

I noticed this package is deprecated, per the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/go-differences

What is the correct way to log on Go 1.12+ **without losing log levels** by simply printing? *(DEBUG/INFO/WARNING/ERROR/CRITICAL/etc.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least 2 solutions :

1. Use [cloud.google.com/go/logging](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/logging)
2. Use a generic logging framework (like [`logrus`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus)) and a special Stackdriver adapter to have logs with the right format and right level in Stackdriver logging

#### Use cloud.google.com/go/logging

This is the default solution I think :

```golang
import "cloud.google.com/go/logging"

ctx := context.Background()
client, err := logging.NewClient(ctx, "my-project")

logger := client.Logger("my-log")
logger.Log(logging.Entry{Payload: "something happened!", Severity: logging.Info})
```

But it can be tedious to create an `Entry` object every time you want to log something. If you want to just write `log.Debug`, `log.Info`, of course you can create functions `logDebug`, `logInfo`, etc, but you can also use another solution (based on logrus).

#### Use logrus and Stackdriver adapter

As I said, you can use [`logrus`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus)) which is pretty common for logging in Go projects. But you need to make a small modification to transform the default text log to a log entry format that Stackdriver can understand.

```golang
import (
        log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
        stackdriver "github.com/TV4/logrus-stackdriver-formatter" // adapter
)

log.SetFormatter(stackdriver.NewFormatter())
log.SetLevel(log.DebugLevel) // default is Info

log.Debug("This is debug")
log.Info("This is info")
log.Error("This is error")
log.Warn("This is warn")
```

Result is the following (notice the right levels) :

[image: Stackdriver logs]

Comment: thanks! is it expected that `context.Background()` will survive through multiple requests on the 1.12+ runtime, even for App Engine Standard?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot help you on this point :/